# Simple Text Capture and Replace with RegEx

Tags: regex, replace, regex-group

Hello I am looking to reorder words in indivudual lines in a sequence of text based on a delimter. I am using http://www.regexr.com/ to do the find and replace. Specifically I want to do something like

```
(capture1) >> (capture2)
```

into something like:

```
(capture2) >> (capture1)
```

On regexr I did something like:

```
/^.*(\w+)>>.*(\w+)$\gm
```

but this does not even match the text.

Aditionally I would like to know the pattern to replace. I'm trying

```
\2 -> \1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there actual brackets in your input, or have you added them for emphasis?

Comment: When reordering the items, are you intentionally removing the "1" from "capture1"?

Comment: capture can be any set of words followed by >> and then by another set of words ending the line. @anubhava

Comment: @Tutleman a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: @stormyone Any set of words, or any set of word characters? That is, would `abc abc >>> def def` match, or just `abc >> def`?

Comment: @Turtleman any sequence of characters/words. So abc abc >>> def def would become def def >> abc abc

Comment: Try: `/^(.*?)>>(.*)$/`

Comment: @anubhava this works but I cannot seem to replace with the capture. I try \2 -> \1 but this does not work.

Comment: @Bohemian just for emphasis

Comment: Try `/^(.*?)>>\s*(.*?)$/gm` --> `$2$1` - see https://regex101.com/r/nD1pC7/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
/^\s*(.*?)\s*>>\s*(.*?)\s*$/gm
```

And replace with `$2$1`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nD1pC7/3).

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of line (since `/m` modifier makes `^` match a line start)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 matching 0+ any chars other than a newline as few as possible up to the first ....
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces before...
- `>>` - literal `>>` sequence
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2 matching the rest of the line up to the first...
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces before...
- `$` - the end of line (due to `/m` the `$` matches the line end).

The `$1` and `$2` are backreferences to the submatches captured with the capturing groups defined in the pattern.

Comment: This will treat the space preceding the `<<` as part of the string, which is probably not what he wants (and is related to the problem in the original regexp he proposed).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
/^\s*(\w+)\s*>>\s*(\w+)\s*$/
```

I think your regex's problem is that there's no space allowed for after the first capture group